# Android bulk insert or ignore JSONArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite, insert

I am receiving a `JSONArray` of data from an ajax call in my application. What would be the best way to do an insert/on conflict skip on a SQLite table in my app? I have the following code:

```
try {
    JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("data");
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    // I don't know what to do here. 
    // Do I do a for loop and convert the entire JSONArray into ContentValues 
    // with the column name and value for each item in the array? 

    db.insertWithOnConflict("Data", null, data, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: so, network and DB are 2 different things, and you should get in the habit of not mixing them.
With that being said, it may be easier to serialize your response so you don't have to manually search for fields in `JSONArray` and `JSONObject`.

Assuming you do want to continue against both suggestions I gave you, JSONArrays are a list, and therefore they don't have a name for each item (that'll be a Map).
Looping through a JSONArray is just like looping on a List (although with some limitations):
        for(int i = 0; i< data.length(); i++) {
            data.get(i);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to write a loop for converting the data from your `JSONArray` to be inserted into your database. If you are using a library which can do that automatically, it does not actually reduce the time of the data processing right?

However, you can minimize your insert operations into your database table by one single database transaction like the following.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = ...
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // do ALL your inserts here
    db.setTransactionSuccessful()
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

You might also consider using an `AsyncTask` to do all these operations in a background thread.

Hope that helps.